# Why is this function composition undefined?

Tags: functions

$$f: \{ 5, 6, 7, 8 \} \to \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}, \,  n \mapsto \begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
(n-1)/2, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

$$g: \mathbb{Z} \to \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}, \,  z \mapsto r, \text{where } z = 11q + r, \, q,r \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } 0 \leq r < 11$$

> **Problem:**
>
> Is $g \circ f$ defined? (yes-no question)

My answer: Yes.

My reasoning: The image of $f$ is $\{ 2, 3, 4 \} \subset \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}$ (the codomain of $f$) $\subset \mathbb{Z}$ (the domain of $g$), of which each element maps once to an element in the codomain of $g$.

My answer, however, was marked wrong. Why is that?

Comment: Is the second function a function of two variables? The notation is confusing!

Comment: @Allawonder $g$ looks to me like a modulo $11$ function

Comment: @Henry Oh, I see now.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(f(5))=g(2)=2$$

$$g(f(6))=g(3)=3$$

$$g(f(7))=g(3)=3$$

$$g(f(8))=g(4)=4$$

thus $g\circ f$ is well defined from $\{5,6,7,8\} $ to $  \Bbb Z /11 \Bbb Z$